# Reading data from xml with php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

please can anybody help me on how to retrieve  data from the xml document below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<livescore-feed timestamp-created="1279745722">
<item id="afab6479053955afcd07dbe2eb972feb" status= "finished" timestamp-starts= "1278255600">
<teams>
<hosts id="zenspbfc_rus">
<name>Zenit</name>
<fullname>FC Zenit St. Petersburg</fullname>
</hosts>
<guests id="anzmfc_rus">
<name>Anzhi</name>
<fullname>FC Anzhi Makhachkala </fullname>
</guests>
</teams>

<events>
<event type="goal" team="hosts">
<player>Bystrov</player>
<minute>15</minute>
<score>1 - 0</score>
</event>
<event type="yellow_card" team="guests">
<player>Tsorayev</player>
<minute>40</minute>
</event>
</events>
</item>
</livescore-feed>
```

i have tried the following and i was able to some data, except from the events node, the events contains some nodes event. the problem i have is how to get the event from the events node

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$match_id = $xml->{livescorefullname-feed}->matches->item[$i]['id'];
echo $match_id;
```

Comment: Your XML doesn't appear to be valid. You open an `<item>` but you try to close a `</items>`

Comment: Thanks for that, it was a mistake i have corrected it

Comment: @GerbenJacobs please any help on how to loop through the <events><event></event><event></event></events>

Answer (score 0):

In SimpleXML, you don't specify the root node, because the SimpleXML object (`$xml`) is the root node.

This loops through each event and outputs the details.

```
foreach($xml->item->events->event as $event){
    echo $event->score;
    echo $event->player;

    echo $event->attributes()->type;
    echo $event->attributes()->team;
}
```